# Svg button path animation

Tags: javascript, css, svg, jquery-animate

I have this SVG button that I'm trying to animate on hover . I want the button to have a blob effect on the hover. I hope you guys can help me out. Here is the link to the SVG

https://codepen.io/haroldhall/pen/ZEJWJqo

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 169.5451 69.2823">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .fbfb67fb-85bf-41e7-ba32-d1082da05d29 {
        fill: #ff83b5;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g id="ee4ac112-3396-4e4b-9bd2-9cf074846425" data-name="Layer 2">
    <g id="b0f8822e-1e1e-4dce-a2e6-9a8bebf20196" data-name="Background">
      <path id="original" class="fbfb67fb-85bf-41e7-ba32-d1082da05d29" d="M76.9857,59.1319C52.7693,55.9614,1.16,89.3257.01,40.4447-.7354,8.7354,38.7113-11.033,76.1673,6.64c33.8056,15.9511,84.1836-17.2117,85.0374,23.6112C162.2335,79.4411,111.2431,65.3513,76.9857,59.1319Z" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS rule `d: path (" M76 .....);` not currently supported by the W3C SVG spec.
This is so far only an experimental technology of browsers based on the Blink engine.

Therefore, a solution based on `rule` d: path` will not be cross-browser, for example Firefox it does not work.

---

*Consider a solution with SVG SMIL.*
[SMIL support](https://caniuse.com/?search=smil%20svg)

To morph the contours of the button, you need to create a final path in the vector editor in the form of a drop

The figures below show the process of getting the final `path` in the vector editor.

[image]

Grab the anchor point and drag it down until you get the desired shape.
Save the svg file and copy the final path to the morph animation command.

[image]

Below is the code for animating the morphing of the button outline into a drop shape:

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 169.5451 69.2823">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .fbfb67fb-85bf-41e7-ba32-d1082da05d29 {
        fill: #ff83b5;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g id="ee4ac112-3396-4e4b-9bd2-9cf074846425" data-name="Layer 2">
    <g id="b0f8822e-1e1e-4dce-a2e6-9a8bebf20196" data-name="Background">
      <path id="original" class="fbfb67fb-85bf-41e7-ba32-d1082da05d29" d="M77 59C53 56 1 89 0 40-1 9 39-11 76 7c34 16 84-18 85 23 1 49-50 35-84 29Z" >
         <animate
           attributeName="d"
           begin="original.mouseover"
           dur="1s"
           fill="freeze"
           restart="WhenNotActive"
           values="
              M77 59C53 56 1 89 0 40-1 9 39-11 76 7c34 16 84-18 85 23 1 49-50 35-84 29Z; 
              M81 113C57 110 1 89 0 40-1 9 39-11 76 7c34 16 84-18 85 23 1 49-45 89-80 83z"
              />
      </path>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure what kind of blob effect you're looking to have, but you can do this either with JS or CSS. Both involve changing the path to the new desired positions. I am including an example that changes a bit on hover. If you need help creating a blob I recommend https://www.blobmaker.app/

```css
svg #original {
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

svg:hover #original {
  d: path("M76.9857,59.1319C52.7693,55.9614,1.16,189.3257.01,40.4447-.7354,8.7354,38.7113-11.033,76.1673,6.64c33.8056,15.9511,84.1836-17.2117,85.0374,23.6112C162.2335,179.4411,11.2431,65.3513,76.9857,59.1319Z");
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 169.5451 69.2823"><defs><style>.fbfb67fb-85bf-41e7-ba32-d1082da05d29{fill:#ff83b5;}</style></defs><g id="ee4ac112-3396-4e4b-9bd2-9cf074846425" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="b0f8822e-1e1e-4dce-a2e6-9a8bebf20196" data-name="Background"><path id="original" class="fbfb67fb-85bf-41e7-ba32-d1082da05d29" d="M76.9857,59.1319C52.7693,55.9614,1.16,89.3257.01,40.4447-.7354,8.7354,38.7113-11.033,76.1673,6.64c33.8056,15.9511,84.1836-17.2117,85.0374,23.6112C162.2335,79.4411,111.2431,65.3513,76.9857,59.1319Z"/> 
   </g></g></svg>
```